How do I stop a users from inputting a letter in the numbers place and vise versa?
How do I stop a users from inputting a letter in the numbers place and vise versa?
Just trying to understand for future learning. I tried to add different types of code to fix this issue, but I'm new at this. Any help would be greatly appreciated.Thnaks.

import java.util.Scanner;
public class Pro_4_extra {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        
        double max = 272.155;
        
        System.out.print("Enter team name: ");
        String team = input.nextLine();
        
        System.out.print("Enter the name of member 1: ");
        String name1 = input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter the weight of member 1 in lbs: ");
        double pounds1 = input.nextDouble();
        input.nextLine();
    
        System.out.print("Enter the name of member 2: ");
        String name2 = input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter the weight of member 2 in lbs: ");
        double pounds2 = input.nextDouble();
        input.nextLine();
        
        System.out.print("Enter the name of member 3: ");
        String name3 = input.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Enter the weight of member 3 in lbs: ");
        double pounds3 = input.nextDouble();
        
        double kilograms1 = pounds1 / 2.2046;
        double kilograms2 = pounds2 / 2.2046;
        double kilograms3 = pounds3 / 2.2046;
        double kilograms = kilograms1 + kilograms2 + kilograms3;
        
      
        
       System.out.println("Team " + team +" members: " + name1 + ", " 
                + name2 + ", and "+ name3);
     
       if (kilograms <= 272.155)                
           System.out.printf("The total weight of the team is %.2f"
                + " kg and is under the maximum. ", kilograms);
       else 
           System.out.printf("The total weight of the team is %.2f kg and is over the limit. "
                + "Your team is disqualified from competing until weight requirements are meet.", kilograms);
            
                
        input.close();
    }   
}


While technically it is possible, it will require quite advanced knowledge of inner working of OS.

Instead of reading the whole line at a time, you can read user input character by character. For example, if you are expecting just digits, you can throw away alphabetic characters and pick up numbers only. Here are some links to give you an idea: take a look at BufferedReader in here and this one. Hope it helps.

a better (and far easier-) approach, would be to validate the input you've read.

Hopefully this is what you are asking. Made 1 method for input and validate that input in case input is not valid ask again or you can also break in between if you want. So it's depend on your requirement.
public static double getValidInput(Scanner scan) {
        while(!scan.hasNextDouble()){
            System.out.println("Please input valid weight !!!");
            scan.next();
        }
        return scan.nextDouble();
    }

Replace your input line with following double pounds1 = getValidInput(input);

optional: add prompting to the method so we can call getValidInput("Enter the weight of member 1 in lbs: ", input)

@user85421 yeah we do that as well
